# boot process recovery or rom

Tags: recovery-mode, boot, bootloader

When I power my device (htc one m8) on and press the volume down key I get into recovery.

Now which part of the booting process checks if this key is pressed and uses the correct partiton (boot or recovery).

Is this the bootloader?

If yes, is this the 'same' bootloader as formerly found in [the aosp tree](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bootable/bootloader/legacy/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial input is read by the *bootloader* to see which partition to boot. *Vol-* will trigger *bootloader*, while no input will trigger *ROM* partition. The bootloader is initially installed by your OEM. No matter what version of Android you have, you still have the same bootloader until you either update your bootloader or install a custom bootloader. The OEM bootloaders are *likely* based off the AOSP tree, depending on your specific phone (I am not sure for the M8).

Comment: Is the selection menu where I can choose between fastboot, recovery and so on already the recovery or is this still the bootloader

Comment: The bootloader has a selection screen when you boot while holding Vol-. It should look like this on your HTC One M8: http://i.stack.imgur.com/48pSP.png

Comment: From the bootloader, you choose which *boot partition* to *load*, hence the name *boot loader*.